# WCF Fault not being propagated to the client properly

Tags: wcf, fault, contracts

We've got the following WCF Service Contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com", Name = "Service1")]
public interface IService1
{      
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(Fault1))]
  ValidateUserResult ValidateUser(
                       string username, 
                       string password);
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com", Name = "Service1")]
public interface IService1Async
{      
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Fault1))]
    IAsyncResult BeginValidateUser(
                       string username, 
                       string password, 
                       AsyncCallback callback, 
                       object userState);

    ValidateUserResult EndValidateUser(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com")]
public class Fault1
{
}
```

We are calling the async version of ValidateUser in the client side and we are throwing a `FaultException<Fault1>` on the server, but all the client receives is the base `FaultException`.

What can be the reason the contractually-specified fault is not being received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found now why. We are generating the fault from a Service Behaviour using the ProvideFault method. There we use code similar to the example at [IErrorHandler.ProvideFault in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault.aspx)

The only difference was that we weren't passing the right action on the `Message.CreateMessage` overload. We copied exactly what gets generated in the case that we manually throw the fault and voila.

My excuses for not giving that last detail :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the catch statements for your call? The contract and everything looks fine to me...

In which order do you check for faults?? You would have to check for `FaultException<Fault1>` **before** checking for `FaultException` or `CommunicationException` - any chance you might have that order mixed up somehow?

Does it work when you call the sync version of the method?